# Applying a function for all subsets of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, subset, split-apply-combine

I am trying to apply a function to each and every subsets of a data frame based on values in two columns. The following example is a simplified representation of my problem.

Say I have the following data frame

```
a=rep(1:5,each=5,times=5)
b=rep(c(2,6,9,10,12),each=25)
t=rep(seq(0,20,5),times=25)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,t))
```

`t` is a time step. and I want to apply a continuous function (means I can't just apply the function for each and every row before sub-setting which will make the task much easier) for each subsets based on a and b values i.e for each `df[df$a==A & df$b==B,]` where `A=1,..,5` and `B=11,...,15`. 
e.g.

```
df[df$a==1 & df$b==12,]
    a  b  t
101 1 12  0
102 1 12  5
103 1 12 10
104 1 12 15
105 1 12 20
```

and the function I want use is dependent on all three variables `(a, b and t)`(e.g. `a^2+b*t-c` where `c` is the result of last time step, this is why I can't just apply the function for each and every row before sub-setting). 
I tried with using functions like `split`/`subset` and `apply`. But I couldn't solve it. Can somebody help?

Comment: have you tested `dplyr` for this problem? So there it would be basically `group_by(a,b) and pipe it to `summarise` and execute your function.

Comment: Yes, `dplyr`s`group_by(a,b) %>% mutate/summarize(...)` is exactly what you want

Comment: Could you please show an example of the result you would like to get?

Comment: You may try: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, your_function(t), by=.(a, b)]
`

Comment: @bouncyball I don't think I can use aggregate as the function i want to use is more complicated.

Comment: @RobertoRuiz I have added some more details. I hope it is clear now?

Comment: Not really. My English is not enough good. I need to see the numbers you want to obtain. I think I have made something similar before.. So (from your example), the result of the row 101 would be 1 and of the row 102 would be 60, and for the 103, 61 ?